# How can I test if a DOM element property is read-only

Tags: javascript, dom, propertyinfo

This is a question about interacting with the DOM using pure Javascript (not jQuery etc)

My ultimate objective is to collect the current values of just those properties of any given DOM element that are writeable, so I want to skip all any properties of the element that are not writeable.

Although I could go through the specs and create a list, specs change, so I would like to do it dynamically (and as efficiently as possible).

I have searched, but come up blank, so any suggestions gratefully welcomed.

PSEUDOCODE: I need a way of implementing is_writable(element)->boolean in the code below

```
let myObject = {};
for (propertyName in HTMLElement) {
    if(is_writable(HTMLElement[propertyName])){
        myObject[propertyName] = HTMLElement[propertyName];
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "element property is read-only"? from `<input>` type elements or `<textarea>` elements or a contenteditable `<div>` ??? where is the code from what you have tried so far? where is your HTML ?

Comment: can you also clarify whether you mean JS object *property* or are you talking about element *attributes*?

Comment: edited the question for more clarity

Answer (score 1):

If a property is writeable can be determined from its property descriptor.
You can get a property descriptor of an object by using Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(). However, this function will only find the object's own properties.

We, therefore, need a function that searches the prototype chain of our object until it finds the property we are looking for and returns the property descriptor:

```
function findPrototypeProperty(object, propertyName){
    while (object && object.constructor && object.constructor.name !== 'Object'){
        let desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, propertyName);
        if(desc){
            return desc;
        }
        object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Property descriptors are Objects that can contain up to 6 values (copied from MDN):

```
value - The value associated with the property (data descriptors only).

writable - true if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed (data descriptors only).

get - A function which serves as a getter for the property, or undefined if there is no getter (accessor descriptors only).

set - A function which serves as a setter for the property, or undefined if there is no setter (accessor descriptors only).

configurable - true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.

enumerable - true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.
```

The first thing to do is to check for the writeable value. If it's true, the property is writeable. You should, however, also check that 'value' is not a function.

Some properties won't have an actual value, but a getter and setter function instead. If a property has a set function, it usually also is writeable.

This is what your is_writeable function could look like:

```
function is_writeable(object, propertyName){
    let desc = findPrototypeProperty(object, propertyName);
    if(!desc){
        return false;
    }
    if(desc.writable && typeof desc.value !== "function"){
        return true;
    }
    return !!desc.set;
}
```

**Conclusion:
Don't do it. Use a list.**

Comment: I want to accept this answer as it is the one that answers my need. I agree a list is best, but this code is a great way to generate one.

Comment: For generating a list the code could work great. You’d just have to watch out for some special properties like innerHtml and outerHtml.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` for checking specific attributes of `DOM Elements`

Like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*[readonly]')
```

will return Array of all elements with `readonly` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a try/catch:

```js
const is_writable = (element, propName) => {
  const originalValue = element[propName]
  try {
    element[propName] = 1  // set it to an arbitrary value
  } catch () {
    return false
  }
  element[propName] = originalValue
  return true
}
```